# On which level of the maven dependency tree are dependencies from the parent project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, dependency-tree

I have a parent pom which has a dependency to third party jar A with version 1.0. Then I have a child project which inherits from the parent pom. This child project defines a dependency to library B which itself has the dependency to the third party jar A with version 1.1.

Does the dependency tree look like this(and therefore version 1.0 is pulled in):

Child->A(version 1.0)
Child->B->A(version 1.1)

On which level of the dependency tree are the dependencies of the parent POM?

Comment: Are you already using the maven dependency plugin? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html
This can help you analyze and eventually view the dependency tree of your module.

Comment: you can invoke `mvn dependency:tree` from the command line to find out. Anyway, dependency `1.0` should "win" over `1.1`, since it is "higher" in the dependency tree. And dependencies inherited from the parent pom are at the top level..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before dependencies are resolved, the parent and child POM are first combined into an "effective POM". You can display the effective POM using `mvn`[`help:effective-pom`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html). Hence your dependency tree becomes:

```
  (Effective POM) -> A:1.0
  (Effective POM) -> B     -> A:1.1
```

The effect is the same as if you had declared the A:1.0 dependency in the child POM. Since dependencies closer to the root "win" in Maven, A:1.0 is used.

Also, if both the parent and child POM declare a dependency to the same module, the version specified by the child overrides the one specified by the parent (= becomes the version in the effective POM).